# Interval of convergence and Uniform convergence of $\sin^n (x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\sin^n(x)$. Find the interval of convergence and prove/disprove that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in this interval.

My attempt: Finding the pointwise limit,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin^n(x)=\begin{cases}
1 \quad\text{if $x=\pi/2+ 2k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$,}\\
\not\exists \quad\text{if $x=3\pi/2+ 2k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$,}\\
0 \quad\text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}$$
From here I'm not sure how to find the interval of convergence and prove or disprove uniform convergence

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is $0$? . What about when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for example

Comment: You should start by thinking for which values of $x$ the series converges. There are 3 different cases, depending on the values of $\sin(x)$. After finding the pointwise limit, think of the fact that uniform convergence of continuous functions implies pointwise convergence too, and the limit has to be continuous..

Comment: You may start with the auxiliary sequence $g_n(y)=y^n,$ $-1\le y\le 1,$ and study its convergence. Then you substitute $y=\sin x.$

Comment: Okay so I messed up here. I've made an edit to the original question after finding (what I think is) the limit.